# Machine Learning Algo for multiclass?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

Which algorithm can be used for multiclass classification where each row is classified into multiple classes?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=multiclass+machine+learning returns 375,000 results. You might want to narrow it down some more.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

For Multi class classification you can use the algorithms -

1. KNN
2. Decision Tree
3. Naive Bayes
4. Random Forest

And, if you are working on any Time Series data, LSTM would be a perfect algorithm to use.

Comment: Good answer, you could also use Support Vector Machines (SVMClassifier) and Neural Networks in general for mulitclass classification .